# Combine multiple columns in a single dataframe with the same name

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to combine a dataframe like the one below so i only ave 2 columns foo and bar.

| foo | foo | bar | bar | bar | foo | foo | bar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | 3 |  | 2 |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 3 | 5 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | 7 | 4 |

The above should become like this:

| foo | bar |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 7 | 4 |

Answer (score 1):

If there are duplicated columns names use `sum` or `mean` or `max` or similar function with `groupby` and `axis=1`:

```
df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).sum()
```

If not duplciated, because suffixes `.1, .2`.. use:

```
df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('.')[0], axis=1).sum()
```